# How can I login to an AngularJS website with python?

Tags: python, angularjs, authentication, python-requests

I've tried reading more than 10 questions here on Stack Overflow on this subject, so forgive me if this' been aswered before. I hardly ever ask questions because I always feel my answer is somewhere in here and all I have to do is look for it, but I gotta admit that I'm at a loss here.

I'm looking to automate downloading a few reports from a specific website (http://ecargo.mercosulline.com.br/), after navigating through it with Python requests module. However, I can't get past the login screen.. haha

If tried many different snippets of code, but I'll paste what I am most "confident" below:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'}     

payload = {
    #'txt_nome':'username',
    #'txt_senha':'password'
    'usuario':'username',
    'senha':'password'
}

url = 'http://ecargo.mercosulline.com.br/SERVICOS/WSMontarMenu.Service.svc/rest/ChecarUsuario'
#url = 'http://ecargo.mercosulline.com.br/NovoIndex.asp'
#r = s.get(url)
#print(r.content)

r = s.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Upon inspecting the page while logging in, I see that my browser makes 2 "POST" requests:

**1st. http://ecargo.mercosulline.com.br/SERVICOS/WSMontarMenu.Service.svc/rest/ChecarUsuario**
with 'usuario' as the field name for username and 'senha' as the field name for password.

**2nd. http://ecargo.mercosulline.com.br/NovoIndex.asp** 
there it uses the webpage form names (txt_nome and txt_senha) as can be seen in the piece of html below:

```
<form name="frmLogin">
                        <br/>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Usuário" name="txt_nome" type="text" value="{{viewModel.usuario}}" autofocus ng-model="viewModel.usuario">
                        </div>

                        <br/>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" name="txt_senha" type="password" value="{{viewModel.senha}}" ng-model="viewModel.senha">
                        </div>

                        <br/>

                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" ng-click="viewModel.logar()">Entrar</button>

                        <br/>
                    </form>
```

If I POST the data in the 1st URL, it doesn't work at all - just gives me an error and says "check server log for more details"
If I post the data in the 2nd URL and print its contents, it just brings me back to the login page.

It seems this page was created with AngularJS so I'm not sure requests module is the right one? Would anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to use your `Browser` [Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) And then navigate to [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor).

Then try to login to the site.

You will notice the following:

[image]

That's mean a `POST` request has been done using `JSON` where you need to use `json=` but if it's `form-data` so you will use `data=`

Check the [document](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) as a ref.

```py
import requests

data = {
    'senha': 'test@test.com',
    'usuario': 'test123'
}

r = requests.post(
    "http://ecargo.mercosulline.com.br/SERVICOS/WSMontarMenu.Service.svc/rest/ChecarUsuario", json=data).json()


print(r)
```

Comment: This worked! The response I got from that URL was satisfactory (showed my username, user ID, etc etc). 3 questions remain: how did you know we had to use JSON? what is the use of the other URL? do I have to pass it as "next"?

Comment: @VictorDias answer updated. please let me know if there's any further questions.

Comment: @VictorDias you welcome :P you can up-vote for my answer if you licked.

Comment: canot yet... need 15 rep